# How to send HTTP requests in Swift 4?

Tags: swift, swift3, swift4

Did anything change in Swift 4? In swift 3 i used this code

```
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://www.centill.website/ajax/logreg.php")!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "ko=1231a"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print(response)
        }

        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        print(responseString)
    }
    task.resume()
```

i wonder if they did any improvements or added anything new.

Comment: You can use Alamofire here https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire. And BTW https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/2139 is their last informations about Swift 4.

Comment: @Janna I installed Alamofire,but when i tried importing it it said "No such module" even though i had all files in pod

Comment: Ok but you might ask a new question for your pod/framework issue. It's easily fixable.

Comment: @Janna Is it necessary to install Cathrage and Swift dependencies or just Alamofire is enough?

Comment: Just setup your project with Cocoapod. Then add this line 'pod Alamofire', '~> 4.4' into your podfile. Run the pod install command on your terminal at your root project. https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html

Comment: Your code should compile and work with Swift 4 (I want to fix some parts to suppress warnings, but it may not be a big issue). Do you have any problems with your code?

Answer (score -2):

try to use this

```
            let strMethod = String(format : "http://www.centill.website/ajax/logreg.php" )

            let params: [String : Any] = ["ko": "1231a"]
            print(params)

            let url = URL(string: strMethod)!

            let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)

            let json = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

            if let json = json {  print(json) }

            let jsonData = json!.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue);

            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.post.rawValue
            request.setValue("application/json; charset=UTF-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

            request.httpBody = jsonData

            Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON {  (response) in
                switch response.result {
                    case .success(let JSON2):
                       print("Success with JSON: \(JSON2)")                        
                       break

                    case .failure(let error):
                       print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
                       //callback(response.result.value as? NSMutableDictionary,error as NSError?)
                        break
                    }
                }
                .responseString { response in
                    print("Response String: \(response.result.value)")
            }
```

Comment: The OP's code does not use JSON both for request and response. Why this code is using JSON?

Comment: if you get any response this will be added in this parameter and print

Comment: if you have not declare then no problem . but in my case i want to do extra thing so i added this type